# T-test with multiple measures per subject

Tags: mixed-model, t-test, repeated-measures, independence

Imagine to have 100 people who have been asked if they are happy 10 consecutive times (time here is not important). Each time we asked, we showed them a card of one color: sometimes green, sometimes of other colors. The same color could appear more than once, over the 10 times.

We want to know if happiness is influenced by the green color. So the idea was to make a t-test comparing green vs not-green and see if the average of happiness was significantly different.

Would that be ok? Probably not, because multiple measurements per subject are not independent.
Which would be the correct approach? (We already have a HLM model, but here we are just interested in comparing means).

Comment: Can you tell us how you set up your multilevel model? If done correctly, you can get the mean difference between green and not-green.

Comment: HLM is set as observations nested in subjects (so observation is level 1 and subjects is level 2). The outcome variable is happiness, and then we have many other predictors, apart from card color.

Comment: You can easily look at the mean difference between green and not green in your HLM by only including `green` as a predictor in your model and no other predictors for card colors. Then the coefficient for `green` is the mean difference between `green` and not green. The HLM accounts for the repeated measures and correlation in happiness through the inclusion of the random intercept for subject. If you include additional predictors in the model beside card color, you are adjusting for those predictors in calculating the mean difference in happiness for green/not-green.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using only one predictor, could I interpret the p-value of the green as a test of significance for the mean difference? In cases where I do not use a multilevel model, is there something else I could use? Like a variation of a t-test?

Comment: Yes, in the case of one predictor, it is a test of the mean difference between green and not green. All the other methods are, in my opinion, worse versions of a multilevel model. Probably the thing people use in these situation is a repeated measures ANOVA. Again, the HLM is better.

Answer (score 2):

No, probably not OK. How large an effect would it be reasonable to suppose that a green card would have on reported happiness? I would be surprised if it caused even a minor change and that means that your experiment will have minimal power and so you would be doing nothing more than noise-mining.

Unless you have some reliable preliminary information that supports a reasonable suspicion that the hypothesis might be true, and the effect large enough to reliably detect with such a small number of participants, then  think long and hard before embarking on a study like that.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data you could possibly do a paired sample t-test, alternative a repeated measure ANOVA.

so it would basically measure the difference between the times they saw the green card. I don't know fore sure if it would be suitable, but its better then a regular t-test in this situation in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks but I am not sure to totally understand how to do that. Which would be the pairs?

Comment: It would depends on your experimental design. Lets say that you show five colours two times a trial. then it could be the difference between those two pairs so spot a difference. In other words, is there i significant change in happy rating between pictures shown.

But i would suggest to do a traditional control/experimental group design.